# Django cache.clear() not working

Tags: django, memcached

I have set up memcached on my machine, and added it to a view like so:

```
@cache_page(3600)
def course_list(request, market_code, destination=None, course_type=None):    
    template = 'course_list.html'
    ...
    ..
```

And I have set up a view that clears the cache when visited

```
from django.core.cache import cache
class ClearCacheView(TemplateView):
    """
    This view will clear the cache and display a message to the user saying so
    """
    template_name = 'ebsadmin/cache_clear_success.html'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        cache.clear()
        return super(ClearCacheView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

When I visit the ClearCacheView, the success template is displayed, but the item in my cache is not deleted.

setings.py

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
        'TIMEOUT':36000

    },
}
```

I have a timestamp in the template, so I can tell that the cache is being used or not:

```
<!-- {% now "jS F Y H:i:s" %} -->
```

cache.clear should clear everything, as far as I understand. So why isn't it doing anything here?

Comment: which django version are you using?

Comment: I am using version 1.9

Comment: Maybe it's a browser caching thing. Have you tried incognito or accessing memcache directly?

Comment: Ok, I tried that. Its still the same. If I put a print statement in the ClearCacheView, then it is reaching that part of the code, but cache.clear() doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Perhaps `memcached` is not running?

Comment: memcached is running, I can telent into it and run stats commands.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the right syntax for clearing the cache as specified in the [`Django cache`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/cache/#memcached) documentation for `Memcached`.

You may need to verify `memcached` daemon is running, if it's not running django cache commands can result with no output. Try re-running it with `memcached` to see if the port is already taken.

Comment: memcached is running - I can telent into it and run stats commands. 
(It would need to be running to store the cache that needs invalidated, wouldn't it?)